# How to execute my javascript function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, call

Here is my code that makes an image move to the right. I have searched how to call and execute functions but I don't understand they.

I know how to execute it in HTML but not in javascript. I want to execute it when I load the page all the time.

```
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight();" />
```

I have seen this code but I can't get it to work with my code.

```
window["functionName"](arguments);
```

like what I'm supposed to write in the brackets for example.

```
<script>
        var imgObj = null;
        var animate ;

        function init(){
           imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
           imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
           imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
        }

        function moveRight(){
           imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 11 + 'px';
           animate = setTimeout(moveRight,22); // call moveRight in 20msec
        }
```

```
<body>

  <form>
     <img id="myImage" src="myimage.jpg" />
     <p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
     <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight();" />
      <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveLeft();" />
     <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop();" />
  </form>
```

Comment: The first thing you want to do is verify your `;` semicolons aren't causing an issue.  They are not required.  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: @Nol — They definitely are not causing an issue. Best practise is to end each statement with a semi-colon and not rely on ASI.

Comment: I'm both dumb and tired.  Took a half second longer to look at it and realized I didn't need to say that.  Seems like the OP problem is that they aren't doing their Init which must be leaving the imgObj empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight extension to @Emil's answer above so that the code will execute as soon as page is loaded.

Using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), providing `moveRight()` as the `function` parameter and `200` as the `delay` will keep calling your function every 200 milliseconds. You can also use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) to cancel the timer.

You may want to extend this further to [prevent image from going off-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759800/stop-image-from-moving-when-reaching-the-border-of-a-container) (if this is a requirement).

```js
var img = document.getElementById("myImage"); 
var imgLeft = 0;
var imgTop = 0;
img.style.position = "absolute";

function render() {
  img.style.left = imgLeft + "px";
  img.style.top = imgTop + "px";
}

function moveRight() {
  console.log(img.style.left);
  imgLeft += 10;
  render();
}
var interval = setInterval(moveRight, 200);
```

```html
<form>
  <img id="myImage" src="myimage.jpg" />      
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `"moveRight();` should do the job. You don't need to do any tricks with `window` because you aren't using a variable to hold the function name.

Comment: Im writing `moveRight();` in the script but when I start the page nothing happens and my buttons don't work either and when I remove `moveRight();` then the buttons start to work again.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: I get this from the console when I try to run moveRight(); 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at moveRight (tset.html:36)
    at tset.html:52
moveRight @ tset.html:36
(anonymous) @ tset.html:52

Comment: Yes, as I said, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 0):

> `window.onload`: Execute a JavaScript immediately after a page has been loaded,
>   You can also put a script tag after an element inside body and it will be executed when the page has loaded.

---

*The code inside the function will execute when "something" invokes (calls) the function*:

- When an event occurs (when a user clicks a button) > `elem.onclick=functionname()`
- When it is invoked (called) from JavaScript code > `functionname()`
- Automatically (self invoked) > `function(){}()`

The `setInterval()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

```js
   window.onload = function(){
  var imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
  imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
  imgObj.style.left = '0px';
  function moveRight(){
    imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 11 + 'px';
  }
  var animate = setInterval(moveRight,222); // call moveRight in 20msec
  document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener("click", function(){
    clearInterval(animate);
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
   <img id="myImage" src="myimage.jpg" />
   <input type="button" value="Stop" id="stop"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `position: absolute`.

```js
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
var imgLeft = 0;
var imgTop = 0;
img.style.position = "absolute";

function render() {
  img.style.left = imgLeft + "px";
  img.style.top = imgTop + "px";
}

function move(x, y) {
  if (x === void 0) {
    x = imgLeft;
  }
  if (y === void 0) {
    y = imgTop;
  }
  imgLeft += x;
  imgTop += y;
  console.log(imgLeft, imgTop);
  render();
}
render();
```

```html
<form>
  <img id="myImage" src="myimage.jpg" />
  <p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
  <input type="button" value="right" onclick="move(10,0);" />
  <input type="button" value="left" onclick="move(-10,0);" />
  <input type="button" value="up" onclick="move(0,-10);" />
  <input type="button" value="down" onclick="move(0,10);" />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't want to use buttons, I want the code to run automatically and I want to execute the function in javascript when I load up the page.